.NET MAUI - Apple CarPlay black screen
I am trying to add Apple Carplay to my .net MAUI app. I follow the tutorial (https://github.com/Suplanus/Xamarin.Demo.Carplay) and after adding UIApplicationSceneManifest block to info.plist i always get black screen when i deploy app to iPhone or Carplay simulator.
I use all latest tools, but problem exists even when creating blank .net MAUI project and adding UIApplicationSceneManifest to info.plist - after that app always shows black screen after splash screen.
Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks!
Add to info.plist:
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
            <dict>
                <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                        <string>UIWindowScene</string>
                        <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                        <string>__MAUI_DEFAULT_SCENE_CONFIGURATION__</string>
                        <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                        <string>DeviceSceneDelegate</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
                <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                        <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                        <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                        <string>BaltosLankos-Car</string>
                        <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                        <string>CarPlaySceneDelegate</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>

Also tried removing "CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication" part - still the same.
I tried with 3 different projects, even a blank one - as soon as i add UIApplicationSceneManifest they all start showing black screen after app launches (on iOS and Carplay). I followed all official documentation steps (MS and Apple) - no luck. I have required Apple entitlements (audio app).
